# Is it possible (if yes, how) can I set link in CToolTipCtrl

Tags: c++, mfc

I need a tooltip to display info about each item in `CListCtrl`.

As a part of info, there is a link.

As I found `CToolTip` display text message, title, icon.

What about link? is it possible?

Comment: I would say the answer is no because under normal circumstances a tooltip is only displayed momentarily. The moment you move the mouse away it usually vanishes. I know you can see the timeout. You have not provided any code as a starting point for someone to advise.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. Create your tooltip (class derived from CTooltip) adding TTS_USEVISUALSTYLE to the styles you use. You will have to modify uFlags member of the TOOLINFO structure before you call SetToolInfo to receive TTN_LINKCLICK notification.

To show a link inside of the tooltip include a link between tags, like this:
"<a href="https://www.google.com">Go Google".
When you hover a mouse over this text the cursor will change to indicate that this is a link.
IT would present another challenge to implement a popup tooltip with a link since it is being dismissed before the user can click on the link. I tested it on the tracking tooltip.

HOWEVER the tooltip is parsing this string as a link, but it does not handle it, you will have to handle click on the link (to the best of my knowledge).